# Как ускорить запросы в БД JDBC

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

Имеется 2 мапы, в одной 120 элементов, в другой 40. Идет перебор, то есть сначала перебираются все элементы мапы 2 с первым элементом первой мапы, все это обращается в БД. Элемент первой мапы + элементы по очереди второй мапы(например: 123456, 456123; 123456, 789654 и тд).

Имеется вот такой класс, с методом, этот метод вызывается каждый раз при итерации перебора двух мап

```
@Service
public class GetDistanceBetweenStationsImpl extends ConnectionDB implements GetDistanceBetweenStations {
// Подключаем логгер
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GetDistanceBetweenStationsImpl.class);

private GetDistanceBetweenStationsImpl() {
}

@Override
public List<Integer> getDistanceBetweenStations(String keyOfStationDeparture, String keyOfStationDestination) {

    ResultSet resultSet;
    CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
    List<Integer> listResult = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Connection connection = getDataSource().getConnection()) {

        // Подготавливаем запрос
        callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(" { call getdistancetest(?,?) } ");

        // Определяем значения параметров
        callableStatement.setString(1, keyOfStationDeparture);
        callableStatement.setString(2, keyOfStationDestination);

        // Выполняем запрос
        resultSet = callableStatement.executeQuery();

        // Вычитываем полученное значение
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            listResult.add(resultSet.getInt(1));
        }
        logger.debug("Get distance for: {}", keyOfStationDeparture + "_" + keyOfStationDestination + ": " + listResult.get(0));
    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        logger.error("Ошибка запроса {} - {}", callableStatement, sqlEx.getMessage());
    }
    return listResult;
}
}
```

То есть как видите, передается 2 кода станций(станция отправления, станция назначения) в базе в процедуре ищется расстояние между этими станциями.

Вот сам код перебора и вызова запроса, тут у меня есть проверка, если данное сочетание уже было, то я в БД не лезу

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Route>> iterator = mapOfRoutes.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<Integer, Route> entry = iterator.next();
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfWagons.size(); i++) {

            String stationCode1 = listOfWagons.get(i).getKeyOfStationDestination();
            String stationCode2 = entry.getValue().getKeyOfStationDeparture();

            String key = stationCode1 + "_" + stationCode2;

            // Заполняем мапы расстояний
            if (!rootMapWithDistanceMoreMaxDist.containsKey(key)) {
                if (!rootMapWithDistances.containsKey(key)) {
                    List<Integer> listDistance = getDistanceBetweenStations.getDistanceBetweenStations(stationCode1, stationCode2);
                    int distance = listDistance.get(0);
                    if (distance == -1) {
                        logger.error("Проверьте код станции {}");
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (distance != -20000) {
                            rootMapWithDistances.put(key, listDistance);
                        } else {
                            rootMapWithDistanceMoreMaxDist.put(key, listDistance);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

У меня проблема в том, что при маленьком объеме элементов в мапе, например 60 в первой и 30 во второй, и в зависимости от повторок, все это конечно работает быстро, около 15 секунд.

Но когда я сделал 120 элементов в первой и 40 во второй, уменьшил количество повторенных элементов в файле, откуда все гружу, то у меня сейчас все это дело работает минуту 45 секунд. И я никак не могу уменьшить это время, я уже половину вынес из запроса, оставил только коды  станций, и все равно.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно ускорить мое обращение к БД, ну не может же быть так, что 3500 запросов так долго работают, я видел как 30 000 запросов за 30 секунд отрабатывают.

Соединение создаю через org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" lazy-init="false"  destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="строка к БД"/>
    <property name="username" value="логин"/>
    <property name="password" value="пароль"/>
</bean>
```

База данный Postgres.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как оптимизировать мне обращение, может какие-то пулы создать? В интернете перепробовал способы, которые предлагались, не помогли мне.

Comment: Зачем такая сложная конструкция? Нельзя сделать один нормальный запрос/процедуру/вьюху и получить требуемое за один раз?

Comment: @IgorKudryashov что вы имеете ввиду? Одним разом не получится сделать, у меня же не один запрос. Просто весь результат уходит дальше в обработку, где перебирается и сортируется.

Comment: Трудно что-либо посоветовать конкретное, непонятна ваша архитектура  и не ясна конечная цель.

Comment: Конечная цель-распределение вагонов по минимальному расстоянию до станции старта рейса. На вход поступает два файла экскль с вагонами где они стоят и рейсами, это как раз и есть две мапы. Далее каждая станция вагона пробегается по станциям старта рейсов. Формируется итоговая мапа с расстояниями и далее уже идет отбор. Вот у меня проблема как раз на формирование мапы с рассттяниями из за медленной отработки толи бд, толи на стороне java

Comment: Попробуйте увеличить размер пула. Возможно в базе данных происходят какие-то сортировки, то вам нужно оптимизировать бд чтобы они выполнялись в памяти а не в свопе.

Comment: @RomanC пул увеличить как раз при получении коннекта в jdbc? Там есть же есть параметр, который по умолчанию 10.

Comment: увеличте значение параметра.

Comment: Я бы для начала изменил функцию `getdistancetest()`. Надо чтобы она могла принимать "начальную станцию" и "массив станций назначения" и возвращала ближайшую станцию из массива. Если массив большой, то можно заранее им заполнить какую-нибудь временную таблицу.

Comment: @IgorKudryashov мне надо весь список вернуть, из него потом формируется окончательное решение

Comment: @RomanC Увеличил параметр, жаль не помогло(( Значит другое решение буду искать

Comment: Должно было помочь, но впрочем вы возможно что-то не то сделали и параметр ваш не работает.

Comment: @RomanC я добавил в настройку соединения <property name="initialSize" value="30"/><property name="maxActive" value="100"/> <property name="maxIdle" value="75"/> <property name="minIdle" value="10"/>

Comment: поставьте initialSize=100

Comment: @RomanC Не вышло(( все равно минута 40 (( может на стороне БД все таки проблема, но неужели 3500 запросов так тяжело для БД

Comment: Это зависит от того сколько времени требуется на выполнение запроса.

Comment: Есть 2 варианта оптимизации: на уровне схемы бд (схема, запросы) и на уровне приложения (кеширование, логика). Хотите скорости - затачивайте структуру бд под них. При проектировании NOSQL на основе запросов формируется схема бд. Если бд реляционная, для ускорения запросов можно применить денормализацию данных, дополнительные индексы. Если нет возможности изменить схему бд, можно сократить расходы, связанные с пересылкой данных через сеть (пул конекшенов, запрашивать больше данных за раз) и частотой просмотра таблиц (делать один большой запрос, вместо нескольких маленьких).

Comment: Конечно одним запросом у меня нет идей как сделать( попробую сделать таблицу куда буду записывать результат и в нее обращаться, если нет в ней записи, то вычислять и добавлять, плюс индекс повешу

Comment: Теперь возникает org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ВАЖНО: извините, уже слишком много клиентов (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be windows-1251, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf). Я почитал, что соединения закрыты должны быть. Но у меня используется конструкция try-with-resources. Вроде как закрываются автоматом соединения